# PathEffect changes the length of the path

Tags: android

I have made a custom view through which I can draw paths, but what I have noticed is that when using setPathEffect on the Paint object, the path is drawn incorrectly, specifically, too short.

For example, the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ASdD.png) is taken from a reply to a different question about path effects, but coincidentally shows the same issue; different patheffects are applied to the same path, but we can see the path ends are clipped differently, when they shouldn't be clipped at all.

This problem seems to be device or android version specific, as it does not appear on a Sony Xperia XA running Android 7, but does on a Samsung A3 2016 running Android 6.